# Eliminating temporary ASP.Net Files

Tags: asp.net, temporary-files

How do you prevent ASP.NET from creating too many temporary files? My website creates gigabytes of temporary files, and that overflows the main partition on the server. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is it in the web site that is creating all the temporary files, and why isn't the web application cleaning up the files itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup a task in the task scheduler to clean up temporary files. I have no idea why this is not done by the OS (or by the creator of those files).

Answer (score 7):

Where are these temp files beeing generated?

If it's in the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder, it's a result of your application beeing recompiled. Checkout [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx) for more information on dynamic compilation. One possible solution could be to [relocate](http://blog.cwa.me.uk/2007/10/15/relocating-temporary-aspnet-files/) the temp directory.

You could try [pre-compiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976.aspx) your site to avoid the generation of temp-files.