# Clean conflicting class files from Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, app-code

Class file Conflicts in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ is preventing me from building the solution. Even though I try emptying out the folder, each time Visual Studio starts the build process, it brings in the class file in to the temp folder with the same folder name. If I restart the machine or leave it overnight, project build without error. Is there anyway to tell Visual studio to delete/ignore/clean any lingering class files that could be in the temp folder?

Clean solution option in VS doesn't work either. Class file in conflict are from the App_Code folder.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932677/what-is-the-shortcut-to-clear-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-before-runing-appl

Comment: also related with some very good info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586790/eliminating-temporary-asp-net-files/592673#592673

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586790/eliminating-temporary-asp-net-files/592673#592673) as an answer here directly: move the temp location for easier cleaning or a pre-build event

```
<system.web>

   <compilation tempDirectory="d:\TempASP.NETFiles\">

      ...

   </compilation>

</system.web>
```

Source was the SO answer, which lead to this:
http://blog.cwa.me.uk/2007/10/15/relocating-temporary-aspnet-files/

Answer (score 5):

Clean, Close all instance of VS, delete the temp files, empty recycle bin, throw pinch of salt over left shoulder. start VS and rebuild all.

works for me at the odd times this happens

Comment: We just threw a pinch of salt over our shoulder in production!

Comment: The salt is the key step

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have not compiled DLL file and not compiled equal class in a project.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pre-build operation on the project to make sure the folder is cleared, it's possibly IIS auto-compiling your app before serving it.

Comment: How do you setup pre-build operations to clean these folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's that you have two class names that are the same: One in your APP_Code and another class as the name of a user control or page.

Comment: This was correct the first time I tried to compile. But then I deleted the conflicting class but the problem did not go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar kind of issue in my project. The files were facing infliction between the files having same name from the current project and an another project. I have resolved it by deleting the files from my project's bin directory whichever i don't wanted.(Still if the problem is not resolved, delete the unwanted files & temporary files from "Debug" and "Release" folders.). This worked 100% in my case.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that this error was popping up when deploying in Azure using pipelines. Looked into the "Temporary ASP.NET folder" to clean it up, but it was empty.
To fix the issue **I packed the class into a namespace** and updated the references to use the full *Namespace.Class* type.