# What is the shortcut to clear “Temporary ASP.NET Files” folder before running application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, temporary-files

The problem is while running my code, i always come up to my old javascript files on VS.2010.
I think its reason is `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder.

How can i clear the temp folder when i press to <kbd>F5</kbd>?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686667/clean-conflicting-class-files-from-temporary-asp-net-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a pre/post-build action (if these are available) which will do the job.